# Qt C++: qglviewer is not getting compiled on Mac OS X 10.7.2

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am trying to compile QT C++ opengl based code on Mac OS X 10.7.2 but it has not been able to find qglviewer.h file.

This is the error I am getting when I compile my code.

```
In file included from src/GLViewer.cc:12: src/GLViewer.h:22:23: error:  
qglviewer.h: No such file or directory In file included from  
src/GLViewer.cc:12: src/GLViewer.h:27: error: expected class-name  
before ‘{’ token src/GLViewer.cc: In constructor  
‘GLViewer::GLViewer(QWidget*)’: src/GLViewer.cc:28: error: class  
‘GLViewer’ does not have any field named ‘QGLViewer’  
src/GLViewer.cc:36: error: ‘camera’ was not declared in this scope  
src/GLViewer.cc: In member function ‘void GLViewer::resetView()’:  
src/GLViewer.cc:48: error: ‘setSceneRadius’ was not declared in this  
scope src/GLViewer.cc:49: error: ‘qglviewer’ has not been declared  
src/GLViewer.cc:49: error: ‘setSceneCenter’ was not declared in this  
scope src/GLViewer.cc:50: error: ‘camera’ was not declared in this  
scope src/GLViewer.cc:55: error: ‘showEntireScene’ was not declared in  
this scope src/GLViewer.cc: In member function ‘void  
GLViewer::setScene(Scene*)’: src/GLViewer.cc:70: error:  
‘initFromDOMElement’ was not declared in this scope src/GLViewer.cc:  
In member function ‘virtual void GLViewer::resizeGL(int, int)’:  
src/GLViewer.cc:89: error: ‘QGLViewer’ has not been declared  
src/GLViewer.cc: In member function ‘virtual void GLViewer::draw()’:  
src/GLViewer.cc:128: error: ‘camera’ was not declared in this scope  
src/GLViewer.cc:134: error: ‘qglviewer’ has not been declared  
src/GLViewer.cc:134: error: expected `;' before ‘cameraPos’  
src/GLViewer.cc:135: error: ‘cameraPos’ was not declared in this scope  
make[2]: \*\*\* [release/GLViewer.o] Error 1 make[1]: \*\*\* [release] Error  
2 make: \*\* [sub-qviewer-make_default-ordered] Error 2
```

Comment: qGLViewer seems to be a third-party library, and is not part of Qt http://www.libqglviewer.com/. Do you have that installed?

Comment: I tried to install libQGLViewer by directly downloading the source file. I followed these intsructions:

    [link](http://www.libqglviewer.com/installUnix.html)

but when I tried to `make` it, it gave me these errors:

  

      `In file included from saveSnapshot.cpp:27:
    ui_VRenderInterface.Qt4.h:13:42: error: Qt3Support/Q3MimeSourceFactory: No such file or directory
    make[1]: *** [.obj/saveSnapshot.o] Error 1
    make: *** [sub-QGLViewer-make_default-ordered] Error 2`

Comment: it seems libqglviewer is really old, and based on qt3. Is there any reason you need to use it? Have you tried using Qt's QGLWidget?

Comment: No I haven't tried Qt's QGLWidget yet but I need libqglviewer because the code I am working on is using `qglviwer.h` and I think it is part of libQGLViewer.

Comment: I read from this [libqglviewerLink](http://www.libqglviewer.com/) that they have resolved the Qt3Support from `ui_VRenderInterface.Qt4.h` but there it still needs Qt3 support for `ui_computerPlayerInterface.Qt4.h`. Here is the error: 

`In file included from computerPlayer.cpp:33:
ui_computerPlayerInterface.Qt4.h:35:42: error: Qt3Support/Q3MimeSourceFactory: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [.obj/computerPlayer.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [sub-Viewer-make_default] Error 2
make[1]: *** [sub-agora-make_default] Error 2
make: *** [sub-examples-contribs-make_default-ordered] Error 2 `

Comment: I am using the new version of libQGLViewer that is 2.3.11 in which I am having above errors.

Comment: Hi @Alexander do you have any idea about this error?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have experience with `libQGLViewer`, so I can't see the solution atm. My only hunch seems like it's trying to use obsolete features of Qt, ones that have been removed in Qt4, so perhaps you could try and do stuff with vanilla Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atlast I contacted QGLViewer Developers and they have fixed this problem. Please follow the instructions given on this link for installation: http://www.libqglviewer.com/index.html

[Please follow on the above page libQGLViewer2.3.14 Version Release]

and to compile your own QGLViewer project please follow this link: http://www.libqglviewer.com/compilation.html#pro

It explains how to create your own `.pro file` to generate the `Makefile`.